Why is this concatenation failing when I order by LEN([FieldName]) in a t-SQL (SQL Server) query?
I have a list of VARCHAR values and I am planning to concatenate them into a single VARCHAR(MAX), and I am looking to do this in a descending length order. So if I have values like "short" and "verylong" then I want to produce a combined value "verylong short"
Done concatenations hundreds of times over the years so I hammered out the code in no time at all and.... it's not working.
I was eventually able to narrow it down to my use of a LEN() in the ORDER BY.
Let me show you:
DECLARE @FOO TABLE
             (
                 [TextValue] VARCHAR(100),
                 [TextLength] INT
             )

INSERT INTO @FOO ([TextValue])
VALUES ('First')

INSERT INTO @FOO ([TextValue])
VALUES ('Second')

UPDATE @FOO 
SET [TextLength] = LEN([TextValue])

Originally I did not have the [TextLengh] column in the table variable, but the need for it will become apparent further down.
When you do a SELECT * FROM @FOO, you'll see that the values are currently in the order I entered them, so "First" (the shorter word) first, and "Second" (the longer word) second:
SELECT * FROM @FOO

this returns:
TextValue   TextLength
----------------------
First           5
Second          6

So easy peasy, right?
DECLARE @CONCAT VARCHAR(MAX)

--First attempt: order by LEN([TextValue]) DESC
SET @CONCAT = NULL

SELECT @CONCAT = CASE 
                     WHEN @CONCAT IS NULL
                         THEN [TextValue]
                         ELSE @CONCAT + ' ' + [TextValue] 
                 END
FROM @FOO
ORDER BY LEN([TextValue]) DESC

SELECT @CONCAT

And here's the "what the ....!?!!?!?!?" moment - the SELECT @CONCAT statement returns
First

The issue arises because of the
ORDER BY LEN([TextValue]) DESC

clause, and that is why I added the [TextLength] column and the update statement. Let's see what happens when I order by [TextLength] instead of LEN([TextValue]):
--Second attempt: order by [TextLength] DESC
SET @CONCAT = NULL

SELECT @CONCAT = CASE 
                     WHEN @CONCAT IS NULL
                         THEN [TextValue]
                         ELSE @CONCAT + ' ' + [TextValue] 
                 END
FROM @FOO
ORDER BY [TextLength] DESC

SELECT @CONCAT

And.... hurray. The output now reads:
Second First

So, fine. It's a problem with a very simple solution, but it leaves me with the following question:
WHY?
Why is it that using an ORDER BY LEN([TextValue]) doesn't work, when an ORDER BY [TextLength], a column that contains the result of the LEN([TextValue]) calculation, DOES work?
What is going on here?

After 20 years, you should know that this way of concating isn't supported and isn't guaranteed to always work, which you now see. Unless you're still sitting on sql server 2000, there are more modern way of concating things, STRING_AGG, FOR XML comes to mind. Nice song though :D

Using the syntax SELECT @Variable = @Variable + ... FROM is a documented antipattern and should be avoided; it relies on the data engine processing your data in a row by row order, which there is no guarantee of. Instead use string aggregation to achieve the same results. In recent versions of SQL Server that would be by using STRING_AGG, however, in older versions you'll need to use FOR XML PATH (and STUFF) to achieve the same results.

Thanks folks! Just shows you that bad habits can creep in if they just happen to work... and then you keep using them until you hit a snag like this.

Okay ... STRING_AGG won't work as I need to ORDER BY, but FOR XML does the job very nicely, thank you both. What do you guys suggest? first one to comment ( siggemmannen ) post suggestion to use FOR XML and I'll accept it as the answer?

Using @siggemannen 's and Thom A's suggestion that I should use FOR XML, the solution would be: SELECT RTRIM(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), (SELECT [TextValue] + ' ' FROM atFOO ORDER BY LEN([TextValue]) DESC FOR XML PATH ('')))) AS [Concat] - If siggemannen wants to post that as an Answer I'd be delighted to flag it as such. (changed table name as SO thinks I was trying to "at" another user

You can use STRING_AGG WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ...) to achieve ordering

"STRING_AGG won't work as I need to ORDER BY" Why doesn't the ORDER BY in STRING_AGG's WITHIN GROUP clause work?
